# Any suggestion to write json data scrape from website in csv in different column

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

Parse data https://pastebin.com/Ydb5Fn9V

I would like to write this data into a `.CSV` file with columns author and text.

I got this data by converting json string

```
json.dumps(data)
```

I tried to write in csv by doing

```
for data in articles:
                dj = json.dumps(data)
                writer.writerow(dj)
                csvfile.close()
```

```
with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns, delimiter='|')
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in articles:
                dj = json.dumps(data)
                writer.writerow(dj)
                csvfile.close()
```

but ran into this error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

If anyone has any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the complete stack trace? it is difficult to locate which line is throwing the error.

Comment: is that the entire file contents? Also, can you provide the actual json in addition to the .dumps?

Comment: 153 
    154     def writerow(self, rowdict):
--> 155         return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
    156 
    157     def writerows(self, rowdicts):